# How can i open the .auz (Authorization File) to Authorize Ableton live 8.2.2

Tags: wine

I want first to say that i am completely new to Ubuntu,i installed it one week ago. I already watched the solutions to this problem and tried them all: i checked on system32 that all the necessary .dll where there and imported the missing ones. To open Ableton live i need to open the authorization (.auz) but i didn't manage and there is no program in the "open with" that allows that. I don't know if adding Ableton live to the open with apps could help, but i don't know how to do that too, i tried looking in the forums but i didn't manage. Maybe this command could be useful $ wine Live.exe "C:\foo.auz"  but i typed it in the terminal and did not work. As i said i am totally new to Ubuntu and don't know how to work with properly. If someone could explain me how to manage to open the .auz file and let Ableton work it would be amazing, cause i am really getting crazy and have no idea how to manage by myself. 
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution;

- Open your file browser and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files, open the `~/.wine` folder then the `C:` folder and Ableton should be in program files.
- Open `Live 8.2.2.exe` (found in `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Ableton/Live 8.2.2/Program`) using Wine Windows Program Loader (right click, open with, wine windows program loader)
- Once Ableton is running drag and drop the `Authorize822.auz` file onto the Ableton window.

You should then get a message telling you that Ableton has been authorised.
Hope this works for you.

Just a small side point, Ableton Live 8.2.2 will run without having been authorised, however you can not save any of your work.

Comment: Of all the people! Hi Luke! You geek.

Comment: Lol, I'm guessing its Lee?